# Spell check a directory containing many files

Tags: linux, bash, spell-checking

What are some different options to spell check files within a certain directory, and print results to a shell? For example, file1 has incorrect spelling at line 4..etc.

Comment: how far you've gone? I meant, the implementation.

Comment: What kind of files are you referring to? If they're text, you can install `spell` (`sudo apt install spell`) and run `find dir -type f -print -exec spell {} \;

Comment: You may take advantage from [spell checker shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734849/) and [spell checking a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453196/).

Answer (score 1):

This is a script that asks the user for a folder to print each filename in the folder and then a sorted list of misspelled words together with the number of times they occur then helps the user correct the listed misspelled words in each file.

```
#! /bin/bash

for f in *.txt ; do 
    echo $f
    aspell list < $f | sort | uniq -c
done

echo "Please correct misspelled words..."

for f in *.txt; do 
    aspell check $f
done
```